# Compression/Decompression library for the iPhone and Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compression, xcode4, php-ziparchive

I have been working on a project that requires downloading a zipped file off a server, and am stuck trying to uncompress it on the iPhone. There appear to be a number of solutions such as [LiteUnzip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/LiteZip.aspx) , [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) and a few others but none so apparently effective as these two. The problem I'm having is making either of them work in my Xcode 4 project.

**LiteUnzip** is in C and I have had extreme difficulty using it. If you have any example code on how to use it to unzip a single zipped file (containing about 60 files), that would be great.

**ZipArchive** seems to be the favorite around here, but I can't get it to compile without errors. I am following the instructions on http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/issues/detail?id=4, building a static library for iphone but I continue to get these kinds of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      -[ZipArchive addFileToZip:newname:] in libziparchive.a(ZipArchive.o)
      _unzReadCurrentFile in libziparchive.a(unzip.o)
```

All the sources I've found have success building in Xcode 3.2, but I am working in Xcode 4.

**Has anybody had success in Xcode 4 with either of these libraries?** Otherwise, do you know of a library that you have had success with?

Comment: I googled _crc32 symbol, and did you include a header file named "zconf.h" ?

Comment: that header is included in the ZipArchive.mm file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using: http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

I'm using it like this:

```
#import "../Objective-Zip/ZipFile.h"
#import "../Objective-Zip/ZipException.h"
#import "../Objective-Zip/FileInZipInfo.h"
#import "../Objective-Zip/ZipWriteStream.h"
#import "../Objective-Zip/ZipReadStream.h"

ZipFile *unzipFile = [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:zippedfile mode:ZipFileModeUnzip];
NSArray *infos = [unzipFile listFileInZipInfos];
```

etc... it's a really straightforward wrapper for ZLib and MiniZip. No need to link static libraries or anything, just import the headers and go.

Comment: Objective-zip moved from code.google to github. New link : https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip